# KumuluzEE JAX-RS API Security with Keycloak - always returns 401 Unauthorized (runs in Docker containers)

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, jax-rs, kumuluzee

I've been following this [guide](https://github.com/kumuluz/kumuluzee-samples/tree/master/kumuluzee-security-cdi-keycloak) on securing my JAX-RS API with Keycloak. I'm doing all the steps it provides, but sadly I can't get my authentication to work right. My requests always result in a 401 response. I hope some of you can help me with this problem.

I use docker-compose to run all containers.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  products:
    image: maven:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./products/target/:/usr/src/products
    command: java -jar /usr/src/products/products-0.0.1.jar
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASS: mysql
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    networks:
      - keycloak

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: keycloak
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: keycloakDb
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8100:8080
    depends_on:
      - keycloakDb
    networks:
      - keycloak

  keycloakDb:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/keycloak/data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - keycloak

networks:
  keycloak:
    driver: bridge
```

I use these settings to configure Kumuluz

`config.yaml`

```
kumuluzee:
  security:
    keycloak:
      json: '{
               "realm": "producerstore-realm",
               "bearer-only": true,
               "auth-server-url": "http://keycloak:8080/auth",
               "ssl-required": "external",
               "resource": "producerstore-api",
               "confidential-port": 0
             }'
```

Here is my JAX-RS application and a REST resource .

`Api.java`

```java
@ApplicationPath("")
@DeclareRoles({"admin", "customer"})
public class Api extends Application {
}
```

`ProductResource.java`

```java
@GET
@PermitAll
@Path("/products")
public Response getAll() {
    try {
        return Response.ok()
            .entity(service.getAll())
            .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return internalServerError(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@POST
@RolesAllowed({"admin"})
@Path("/products")
public Response createProduct(ProductDto productDto, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    try {
        long createdId = service.add(productDto);

        URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder()
                            .segment(Long.toString(createdId))
                            .build();

        return Response.created(uri)
            .build();
    } catch (CreationException e) {
        return internalServerError(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I've also defined the admin and customer roles in Keycloak. Next I made a user and assigned these roles to them.

When I log in with that user I receive a correct JWT.

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8100/auth/realms/producerstore-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=producerstore-app&username=<username>&password=<password>'
```

which results in the following token

```
{
    "access_token": "<very-long-token>",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "<another-very-long-token>",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "session_state": "770908df-08fa-4935-8666-a58ae41447e7",
    "scope": "profile email"
}
```

But when I try to request my resource, it always results in a 401.

```sh
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8000/products \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <very-long-token>'
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /products. Reason:

            <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.15.v20190215</a>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope some of you can help me with this problem, if you need more information about something i'll happily provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that the token issuer URL doesn't match the realm URL in the configuration.
Try using the following keycloak docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
version: '3'

keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: keycloak
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: keycloakDb
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - keycloakDb
    networks:
      - keycloak
```

Add `keycloak` mapping to you hosts file in order for you to access `keycloak` outside docker.